# Add Sqreen require before Nuxt

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt doesn't provide anything by default to be run before the Nuxt CLI is hit. I am trying to integrate Sqreen (WAF service), and thus it asks me to include sqreen before anything else on my node server.

Is there any way to require this before Nuxt starts? I currently added the require('sqreen'); as a plugin within the nuxt.config.js, but this is obviously triggered after the Nuxt CLI.

[image]

Comment: You can create your own launch script, see example in create nuxt-app repo

Comment: @Aldarund what repo would that be exactly?

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/blob/master/template/server/index-express.js